# Android FTP Download

Tags: android, apache, ftp

I am using the following code segment to download a file to the SD Card of an Android phone. In the Wireshark trace I see the file is transferred and the FTP transfer complete message as well. But the file in the SD card is zero size. All required permissions are set in the manifest file. Can anybody help? Not working with FileOutputStream either.

```
       try{
       ftpClient.connect(InetAddress.getByName("xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx"));        
       ftpClient.login("xxxx", "xxxxx");
       ftpClient.changeWorkingDirectory("xxxx");
       ftpClient.setFileType(FTP.BINARY_FILE_TYPE);
       ftpClient.enterLocalPassiveMode();

       //FileOutputStream desFileStream = new FileOutputStream("/sdcard/test25.txt");
       BufferedOutputStream desFileStream = new BufferedOutputStream(new FileOutputStream("/sdcard/test25.txt"),8*1024);

         boolean status=ftpClient.retrieveFile("test.txt", desFileStream);

         if(status){
        Toast toast = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Downlaoded", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
        toast.show();
         }

       //desFileStream.flush();

       ftpClient.logout();
       ftpClient.disconnect();

       }

       catch (IOException e){
        Toast toast = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Error", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
        toast.show();
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why is the .flush() call commented out? Have you tried .flush()'ing and .close()'ing ?

According to the [documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/io/BufferedOutputStream.html):

> flush()
>
> Flushes this stream to ensure all pending data is written out to the
>   target stream.

Comment: flush and close both generates an IOException.

Comment: 05-04 14:34:46.866: W/System.err(1834): java.io.IOException: No space left on device        This is bit surprising. There is around 7G free in the SD card and the target file is only 32 KB. Let me check more. Thanks

Comment: Many thanks, Apparently disk was filled with some unexpected stuff. Cleared and works just fine.

Answer (score 1):

You need to close the output stream after done writing to it:

```
BufferedOutputStream desFileStream = new BufferedOutputStream(new FileOutputStream("/sdcard/test25.txt"),8*1024);
boolean status=ftpClient.retrieveFile("test.txt", desFileStream);
desFileStream.close();
```

Comment: I tried it, But closing pops an IO Exception. Apparently by inside the Apache commons code. Same happened for flush as well.